# Do many people print e-books?

Tags: ebook

Should I optimize my nonfiction e-book for screen viewing or for printing?

Does it make sense to optimize a e-book for printing, do many people really print e-books?

Comment: I would think, nowadays, with the proliferation of pads and e-readers, few people would bother to print ebooks. That is just conjecture, however, I have no statistics upon which to base this :)

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you mean by "optimize...for printing," in the context of your nonfiction book.  Is your book only text, or does it have a bunch of illustrations, charts, figures, etc.?

Comment: I'm not even sure if printing an ebook is legal (as you are creating a copy of it, wouldn't it violate copyright?) Obviously that doesn't apply your work is licensed under creative commons or a similar scheme

Answer (score 2):

Optimizing an ebook for screen is the more difficult course because you have multiple page sizes. If it works well at any size it will work fine for printing. The reverse is not true.